# Google-chrome on AWS Lambda

Tags: google-chrome, lambda, chromium

It is possible to run Google-chrome not Chromium with puppeteer in AWS Lambda with container?

Script stuck when I create new page in browser:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

Logs from AWS lambda:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/.local’: Read-only file system
touch: cannot touch ‘/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 45: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 46: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory
[0213/000419.523205:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0213/000419.528197:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0213/000419.648505:WARNING:audio_manager_linux.cc(60)] Falling back to ALSA for audio output. PulseAudio is not available or could not be initialized.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:46195/devtools/browser/1d348770-1c99-48a5-934c-fae5254fc766
[0213/000419.769218:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS) failed
```

Comment: Have you get this fixed? I'm facing similar issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76998462/google-chrome-tries-to-create-mimeapps-list-on-ubuntu-docker-image-hosted-on-aws

Answer (score 1):

I do not use puppeteer but that doesn't matter much.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
RUN yum install unzip atk at-spi2-atk gtk3 cups-libs pango libdrm \
    libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXtst libXt \
    libXrandr libXScrnSaver alsa-lib \
    xorg-x11-server-Xvfb wget shadow-utils  -y

COPY install-chrome.sh /tmp/

RUN /usr/bin/bash /tmp/install-chrome.sh

ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="/dev/null"
```

I am not 100% DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is necessary. I am also not 100% sure whether explicitly naming all these packages are necessary, I stole everything from a dozen different places, likely the chrome rpm will pull in what it needs, but I never used any RHEL based system so I am totally clueless. I know this works. Optimizations are welcome.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Download and install chrome
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
# Without -y it doesn't run because it needs to add dependencies.
yum install -y google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
rm google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

CHROMEVERSION=`wget -qO- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`
wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEVERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt
rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEVERSION
chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEVERSION
ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEVERSION /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Create a user. /usr/sbin is not on $PATH.
/usr/sbin/groupadd --system chrome
/usr/sbin/useradd --system --create-home --gid chrome --groups audio,video chrome
```

You can verify it is working by starting it locally with `docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp --read-only` this simulates well the environment of AWS Lambda. Then you need to run `su chrome -c 'xvfb-run chromedriver --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1'`. I am using https://github.com/instaclick/php-webdriver/ which is a very thin PHP client for W3C and Selenium 2 webdriver. I used this to test:

```php
<?php

namespace WebDriver;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

@mkdir('/tmp/chrome');
chmod('/tmp/chrome', 0777);
$wd_host = 'http://localhost:9515';
$web_driver = new WebDriver($wd_host);
$session = $web_driver->session('chrome', [['goog:chromeOptions' => ['args' => [
  '--no-sandbox',
  '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome'
]]]]);
$session->open('https://google.com');
```