# google-chrome tries to create mimeapps.list on Ubuntu Docker Image hosted on AWS Lambda crash due to readonly directory

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, aws-lambda, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have created an Ubuntu Docker image and am using it as a Lambda function. I have completed all the prerequisites, such as installing the [lambda-runtime-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-ric). The Docker image was built with the installation of google-chrome-stable drivers to be used by [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) for a web crawling application. I just want to mention that I already tried [chrome-aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-aws-lambda), but it did not fulfill our requirements. We need the latest Puppeteer npm package, so I am building a custom Docker image with Ubuntu, and it is working fine in a containerized environment ([ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)).

The issue:
When run on AWS Lambda when request received and browser launched by puppeter function crash and below is stacktrace.

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/sbx_user1051': Read-only file system
touch: cannot touch '/home/sbx_user1051/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 45: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 46: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.
[35:35:0828/093835.966383:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

This is my function/args for launching chrome through pupeteer

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new", executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome', ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'], args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox','--no-default-browser-check'], timeout: 0,  protocolTimeout: 24000000 });`

I knew in Lambda only directory for writing file in '/tmp' but I could not find how to change chrome configuration to use '***/tmp***' dir instead of '***/home/sbx_user1051/.local/share/applications/***'

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl wget -y

#Installing NodeJS 16
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs

# Installing dependencies for Google-chrome
RUN apt install -y libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7 libasound2 libgconf-2-4 libnspr4 libnss3 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 xauth xvfb

RUN apt install -y libatk-bridge2.0-0 fonts-liberation libatspi2.0-0 libgbm1 libgtk-4-1 libu2f-udev libvulkan1 libxkbcommon0 xdg-utils

# Installing Google-chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -f
RUN google-chrome --version

# Installing dependencies for Lambda runtime interface
RUN apt-get install -y \
g++ \
make \
cmake \
unzip \
libtool \
libcurl4-openssl-dev

# Installing lambda runtime interface
RUN apt-get install cmake -y
RUN apt-get install autoconf -y
RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric

# Copy function code
COPY / ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN npm install

ENV NPM_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/.npm
ENV CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR=/tmp/chrome

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/npx", "aws-lambda-ric"]
CMD ["index.handler"]
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I am using the official puppeteer docker image but the end error is the same.

Comment: I also ended up with this error, could not find any support of it and very limited options available for AWS Lambda